# Why I got this Error android.view.InflateException ... Binary XML file line #12 ... #25: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton?

Tags: java, android

Please help me!!!
I really need your help to solve this problem:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fblogin.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="@string/facebook_app_id" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.16.0'
}
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.urma....MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/facebook_button_login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements FacebookCallback<LoginResult>{

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

LoginButton buttonLogin;
CallbackManager callbackManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    buttonLogin = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.facebook_button_login);
    buttonLogin.setReadPermissions("email", "user_friends");
    buttonLogin.registerCallback(callbackManager, this);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult: " + resultCode);
}

@Override
public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onSuccess: AccessToken " + loginResult.getAccessToken()
    + "Granted: " + loginResult.getRecentlyGrantedPermissions()
    +" Denied: " + loginResult.getRecentlyDeniedPermissions());
}

@Override
public void onCancel() {}

@Override
public void onError(FacebookException error) {}
}
```

I do not know what is the problem. For the second day, I can not solve this. I would be very happy if you help.

Comment: Try calling FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize before setContentView.

Comment: Ohhh my god!!! Thank you very much!!! The problem is solved!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to initialize the Facebook SDK first

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put these two lines:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
```

just after:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
.....
}
```